# How to pause charging for Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have simplest version of `PHP` elastic beanstalk server. It has single virtual machine `EC2` instance and it, in turn, has `gp2` volume attached.

In order to pause charging, should I just stop `EC2` virtual machine? Will everythong restore if I run machine next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pause the EC2 instance you won't be charged for the computing capacity (as it's stopped) but you'll be charged for the EBS volume as you're using that space.

If you do not want to be charged for this then stop your instance, take a snapshot of the volume, save it somewhere in the cloud or your local machine, and then remove both the EC2 instance and the volume. The next time that you launch your EC2 instance you can import your snapshot and your data will be there again.